# Lucky Master Chief?

Tags: halo

In the final mission of Halo 3 (Halo) the Chief prematurely fires Installation 04B, destroying the Halo, the Ark, etc. shouldn't he have died, though, immediately after firing the ring? How did he survive?

Answer (score 4):

Remember that, in the post-credits scene, Cortana said to Master Chief:

> We made it to the portal just as it collapsed.

So what I think happened here is that the explosion somehow changed the portal's behavior sending the ship's part where Master Chief and Cortana was to one way, and the other part where the arbiter was to another way. But yes, Master Chief was very lucky.

Comment: Comments have been made on his luck since the first novel. It's his thing.

Comment: @PointlessSpike As noted in [Fall of Reach](https://books.google.com/books?id=q09de7IECAkC&pg=PA270&dq=halo+he+is+the+bravest+and+quite+possibly+the+luckiest&hl=en&sa=X&ei=kn7VVJ16kPywBJaHgIgJ&ved=0CB0Q6AEwAA#v=onepage&q=halo%20he%20is%20the%20bravest%20and%20quite%20possibly%20the%20luckiest&f=false) - `But he is the bravest - and quite possibly the luckiest. And in my opinion, he is the best.` (Dr. Halsey, discussing John and the other Spartan-IIs with Cortana)

Comment: I can one-up you- the start of Halo 3. "They let me pick, did I ever tell you that? Choose whichever Spartan I wanted. You know me. I did my research. Watched as you became the soldier we needed you to be. Like the others, you were strong and swift and brave. A natural leader. But you had something they didn't. Something no one saw... but me. Can you guess? Luck. Was I wrong?"